# Bringing lastest values for each day

Tags: sql, sql-server

hope you're doing well
Having some issues with querying data, being trying with different answers to previous posts but can't solve it.
I got data for some products, and the records show that in one day people might change the price or cost of an item several times, so I need to get the last record fixed for each day / item.
This would be an example of the database records:
[Table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQ5q6.png)

What would you sugest in order to bring one record per date per item?

I already tried this, but it brings the same date for each record:

```
SELECT
Product,
Date,
Price_of_item,
Cost_of_item

FROM server 
WHERE DATE IN (SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM server GROUP BY DAY(DATE))
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Tag our question with the database you are using.

Comment: What is your expected output. Please edit the question and show that.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We really need to know what database you are using to provide accurate answers. Hopefully one of these variants works for you

Using common table expressions:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT product
  ,DAY(DATE) as day
  ,MAX(DATE) as maxdate
FROM server 
GROUP BY product,DAY(DATE)
)
SELECT
  CTE.Product,
  CTE.MaxDate as Date,
  s.Price_of_item,
  s.Cost_of_item
FROM CTE 
INNER JOIN server s 
   ON CTE.product=s.product and CTE.MaxDate=s.Date
```

Using analytical functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       product
      ,FIRST_VALUE(DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY Product,DAY(DATE) ORDER BY Date DESC) as Date
      ,FIRST_VALUE(Price_of_item) OVER (PARTITION BY Product,DAY(DATE) ORDER BY Date DESC) as Price_of_item
      ,FIRST_VALUE(Cost_of_item) OVER (PARTITION BY Product,DAY(DATE) ORDER BY Date DESC) as Cost_of_item
FROM server
```

The ouput of these should both be:

```
Product Date            Price of item   Cost of item
C       2/9/2020 13:20  20              5
C       5/9/2020 18:10  22              8
A       12/9/2020 18:50 31              16
```